# Could not find a match

Tags: c++, class, match

I get the following error and I cannot figure out why:

```
Could not find a match for 'PEmployee::PEmployee(char *, double)' in function main()
```

**Here's my code:**

```
class PEmployee
{
    public:
        PEmployee();
        PEmployee(string employee_name, double initial_salary);
        void set_salary(double new_salary);
        double get_salary() const;
        string get_name() const;
    private:
        Person person_data;
        double salary;
};

int main()
{
    PEmployee f("Patrick", 1000.00);
    cout << f.get_name() << " earns a salary of ";
    << f.get_salary() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why I get this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Remark unrelated to the problem at hand: You shouldn't have a semicolon `;` after `"earns a salary of "` since the expression continues into the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `std::string` with type `char *` is not explicit, so I don't know why you would get that error. The compiler should recognize that it can create a `std::string` on the fly for you.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string:

> basic_string( const CharT* s,
>                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );

Comment: Perhaps `string` isn't actually `std::string` here.

Comment: Or it's just forward-declared in another header (e.g. `<iostream>`).